# How to get proper string array in swift?

Tags: ios, swift3

```
["[\"1\", \"7\", \"13\", \"19\", \"25\"]", "[\"6\", \"12\", \"13\"]"]
```

I am getting this as output how to get string array like this in Swift

```
["1", "7", "13", "19", "25", "6", "12", "13"]
```

I tried all to convert this array in proper array but no luck. Is there a solution for this ?

Thank You!!

Comment: what is your trying sofar?

Comment: @Pratik Sanap you need to remove or replace occurrence of "\" before appending to array.

Comment: Edit your question to include the code you used to create the array.

Comment: there was optional string present in array I removed that. and also I tried to replace "\" with " " but no luck

Comment: thank you guys for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple solution (without significant error handling), the strings can be treated as JSON

```
let array = ["[\"1\", \"7\", \"13\", \"19\", \"25\"]", "[\"6\", \"12\", \"13\"]"]

var result = [String]()
for item in array {
    let jsonArray = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: item.data(using: .utf8)!) as! [String]
    result.append(contentsOf: jsonArray)
}
print(result)
```

Comment: Or `let result = array.flatMap { try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: $0.data(using: .utf8)!) as! [String] }`

Answer (score 1):

First, assuming you had a simple array of arrays, you can flatten it with `flatMap`:

```
let input = [["1", "7", "13", "19", "25"], ["6", "12", "13"]]
let output = input.flatMap { $0 }
```

That outputs

> ["1", "7", "13", "19", "25", "6", "12", "13"]

Or, even easier, just append the second array to the first one, bypassing the array of arrays altogether:

```
let array1 = ["1", "7", "13", "19", "25"]
let array2 = ["6", "12", "13"]
let output = array1 + array2
```

But your example looks like it's not an array of arrays, but rather array of descriptions of arrays, e.g. something like:

```
let array1 = ["1", "7", "13", "19", "25"]
let array2 = ["6", "12", "13"]
let input = ["\(array1)", "\(array2)"]

let output = ...                       // this is so complicated, I wouldn't bother trying it
```

Rather than figuring out how to reverse this array of interpolated strings, I'd suggest you revisit how you built that, bypassing interpolated strings (or `description` of the arrays).